# Issue with nginx redirect

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have the following nginx.conf:

```
events {
      worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
    }

    http {
    server {
            listen 443 ssl default_server;
            server_name www.artelazer.com.br artelazermoveis.com.br;
            ssl_certificate /var/webapps/loja/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /var/webapps/loja/privkey.pem;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
    }
    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name www.alexalonso.com.br alexalonso.com.br;
            ssl_certificate /var/webapps/alexalonso/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /var/webapps/alexalonso/privkey.pem;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.alexalonso.com.br alexalonso.com.br artelazermoveis.com.br www.artelazermoveis.com.br;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }







    }
```

What I wanna it to do is: every time a request comes on port 80, redirect it to https.
What is actually doing: when I try to access http://alexalonso.com.br, it works as expected, it redirects to `https://alexalonso.com.br`. But when I try to access artelazermoveis.com.br, it redirects to `https://alexalonso.com.br`.

It's my first contact with Nginx, so I would be glad if anyone could help!

Comment: BTW: Using name based different certificates on the SSL port might cause problems with clients who'd not sent SNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$server_name` expands to the (first) name of the Server definition not to the hostname requested. That would be `$host` instead (it defaults to server_name if the request does not specify one.